# Getting value from String array - Java

Tags: java, android

I'm making an anagram game, and I have a String Array of words, e.g

```
String[] answers = {"yes", "hello", "goodbye", "after", "christmas"};
```

I also have a level integer

```
int currentLevel = 0;
```

Now, when an answer is typed in to the text field, it will compare it to the answer of the current level from the array, using the following code

```
TextView currentGuess = findViewById(R.id.currentGuess);
if(currentGuess.getText().toString().equals(answers[currentLevel])) {
    //execute code
}
```

This is working fabulously well, until it reaches array word 3 (after), then it keeps saying Incorrect, I have tried changing the word and still get the same result, I have also tried printing the answer on the page, just to check it was comparing to the correct word, and everything was fine.

I'm totally stumped on this one, it's my only barrier in this game.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code where `currentLevel` is actually incremented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have a capital level where `currentLevel` is incremented. Try to make it so that it's as follows:

```
TextView currentGuess = findViewById(R.id.currentGuess);
if(currentGuess.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals(answers[currentLevel])) {
    //execute code
}
```

Comment: I tried this, didn't work. Where the execute code is, the code that's going there is as follows: currentLevel = currentLevel + 1;

It's just weird because it's working fine until I get to the word after (number 3)

Comment: Problem solved, was toUpperCase() that was needed. My bad, sorry, thanks for your help!! Life saver